# How to run two different DB's click event using third DB

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two databases in MS Access having different codes, but both have unique form i.e form2. Now i have form in third database and i want run database 1 and database 2 form2 click event using this form.

I have code for this purpose on third form and code is running both db's form correctly but click event not running at that time.

My code is given below

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
OpenRemoteForm "C:\Data\Offer\Chrome\Main_Ch.accdb", "Form2", "Command17_Click()"
End Sub

Function OpenRemoteForm(strDbFile As String, strFormName As String, strclick As String)
    Dim objAcc As Object
    Dim accFrm As Object
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdAppMinimize
    Dim strBookmark As String

    Set objAcc = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    objAcc.OpenCurrentDatabase (strDbFile)

'    objAcc.DoCmd.OpenForm strFormName
'    With objAcc.Forms(strFormName)
'        Set rst = .RecordsetClone
'        rst.FindFirst strKeyFieldName & "=" & lngIDToFind
'        If rst.NoMatch Then
'            MsgBox "No Match"
'        Else
'            .Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
'        End If
'    End With

    objAcc.UserControl = True

End Function
```

When i press button on third db form then click event should be run of DB 1 form2 and DB2 form2 simultanously.

Comment: anybody have some idea regarding above form issue

Comment: Code opens and manipulates only 1 db. So what do you mean by 'simultaneously'?

Answer (score 0):

There is no code in that procedure to call procedure in other db. If you want to call form procedure from 3rd db, procedure cannot be Private. Remove private qualifier from button Click event declaration in the two dbs.

Form name can definitely be passed in a variable and referenced that way. Must open form before calling procedure.
`objAcc.DoCmd.OpenForm strFormName`

Referencing form procedures is trickier. One approach is to give both buttons same name and explicitly reference that name.
`objAcc.Forms(strFormName).Command17_Click`

Another approach uses CallByName intrinsic function which does allow passing procedure reference in a variable.
`CallByName objAcc.Forms(strFormName), strClick, vbMethod`
Have to remove parentheses from the strClick parameter.
`OpenRemoteForm "C:\Data\Offer\Chrome\Main_Ch.accdb", "Form2", "Command17_Click"`

If you want to open db and then just hand control over to user, really don't even need all this code declaring and setting application objects. Have code behind those forms to run their own button Click event using Open or Load events. If form is set to open by default when db opens, then code in those events should execute when db opens. Methods for simply opening a file use FollowHyperlink or Shell commands.

Recommend assigning more meaningful names than defaults assigned by Access.